# Laravel groupBy performance slow

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm working in one of my Laravel 8 projects and need to parse dates of my returned query for formatting with my graph. My query, which returns around 70,000 rows takes around 100ms, but upon further debugging, the `getUptimeTimeline` function in my project which takes the results of my query as `$uptimeChecks` is taking 800ms for just the `groupBy` part.

How can I improve this performance or maybe exclude it entirely?

The query results passed to my function are:

```php
$uptimeChecks = UptimeCheck::where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->where('monitor_id', $monitor['id'])
    ->where('checked_at', '>=', $from)
    ->where('checked_at', '<=', $to)
    ->orderBy('checked_at', 'asc')
    ->select('event', 'response_time', 'checked_at')
    ->get();
```

Here's my function:

```php
/**
 * Get uptime timeline
 *
 * @return Response
 */
protected function getUptimeTimeline($user, $id, $uptimeChecks, $period, $days)
{
    try {
        $start = microtime(true);
        $dates = collect($period->toArray())->mapWithKeys(function ($date) {
            return [$date->format('Y-m-d') => [
                'total_events' => 0,
                'down_events' => 0,
                'up_events' => 0,
                'uptime' => 'No Data',
                'fill' => '#ced1d7',
            ]];
        });

        $end = microtime(true);
        Log::debug('timeline_1', [
            'diff' => ($end - $start) * 1000
        ]);

        $start = microtime(true);
        $uptimeDates = $uptimeChecks->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
            $date = Carbon::parse($item->checked_at);

            return $date->format('Y-m-d');
        });

        $end = microtime(true);
        Log::debug('timeline_2', [
            'diff' => ($end - $start) * 1000
        ]);

        return $uptimeDates;
    } catch (\Exception $e) { }
}
```

It's the `timeline_2` results which is slow.

#### UPDATE

```php
$responseTimes = UptimeCheck::where('user_id', $user->id)
                            ->where('monitor_id', $monitor['id'])
                            ->where('checked_at', '>=', $from)
                            ->where('checked_at', '<=', $to)
                            ->orderBy('checked_at', 'asc')
                            ->select('event', 'response_time', 'checked_at', DB::raw('DATE(checked_at) as check_date'))
                            ->groupBy('check_date')
                            ->limit(10)
                            ->get();
```

Attempting to run a `select` containing `DB::raw()` throws an error:

> [2023-01-30 20:42:31] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'domainmonitor_db.uptime_checks.event' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `event`, `response_time`, `checked_at`, DATE(checked_at) as check_date from `uptime_checks` where `user_id` = 1 and `monitor_id` = 1 and `checked_at` >= 2022-12-26 20:42:31 and `checked_at` <= 2023-01-30 20:42:31 group by `check_date` order by `checked_at` asc limit 10) {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 42000): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'domainmonitor_db.uptime_checks.event' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `event`, `response_time`, `checked_at`, DATE(checked_at) as check_date from `uptime_checks` where `user_id` = 1 and `monitor_id` = 1 and `checked_at` >= 2022-12-26 20:42:31 and `checked_at` <= 2023-01-30 20:42:31 group by `check_date` order by `checked_at` asc limit 10) at C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\web-projects\domain-monitor\domain-monitor-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:760)

Comment: It is slow because you are groupping by on a collection... how many resources you have inside that collection? Of course it is going to be slow... And taking 800ms for 70k is awesome... you should be groupping by on the query, not on the collection...

Comment: Please provide an example based on my query and PHP groupBy?

Comment: try doing `select('event', 'response_time', 'checked_at', DB::raw('DATE(checked_at) as check_date'))` and then you can do `groupBy('check_date')` see if that speeds things up a bit. There's not that much you can do given your question. Whether you can further speed It up depends how you plan to use all that data, there might be things you could safely omit or even add some sort of pagination.

Comment: @apokryfos adding this throws an error. See my updated description, basically it complains about my `event` column. For context, my `event` column can only ever contain two strings, either **up** or **down**

Comment: This is probably why I went with the collection based approach after the data has been returned, but, it's slow.

Comment: You should never have more than 1k (I could say 10k) items inside a collection... you are using a LOT of memory and CPU, you must solve it using the database. I may be totally confused, but I think you can do `->groupByRaw('DATE(checked_at))` or something similar, the idea is to let the DB do that, it is hyper performant for doing that

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself well. The `groupBy` is meant to replace the one you already have in the 2nd function

Comment: @apokryfos it is really unrecommended to do groupBy inside a collection , especially with 70k rows of data (and in the future we can presume will be more).

Comment: @Win `groupBy` on a collection has a completely different behaviour that `groupBy` on a query. You cannot achieve the same result using `groupBy` on the query. Whether or not it is wise to operate over 70k rows is a different topic entirely but without enough information on what the result is used for I cannot know if there are things that can be done to reduce the result size.

Answer (score 0):

You should group the item during the query and handle other column properly on how you want like combine, sum, min, max or whatever that belongs to a group

here's an example grouping your query by checked_at and combing the values of other columns you want to select.

```
$uptimeChecks = UptimeCheck::select(
        DB::raw('group_concat(event) as events'), // this combines event column values belongs to a group
        DB::raw('group_concat(response_time) as responses_time'), // this combines response_time column values belongs to a group
        'checked_at'
    )
    ->where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->where('monitor_id', $monitor['id'])
    ->whereBetween('checked_at', [$from, $to])
    ->groupBy('checked_at')
    ->orderBy('checked_at', 'asc')
    ->get();
```